# How to listen when a fragment is on the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

What I need is exactly an `onResume` method (as it works for activities) for a specific fragment. I'm adding the fragment (let's say fragment A) to the back stack, and opening another fragment (fragment B) (again adding to back stack) from fragment A. I want to update toolbar when fragment B is closed and fragment A is on screen again. I expect `onCreateView` to get called but it's not getting called when I pop fragment B. I also tried adding an `OnBackStackChangedListener` to fragment A but then I cannot track which fragment is on the screen when the back stack changes.

So my question is how to make `onCreateView` get called when I turn back to fragment A. And if this is not a good practice, how else can I track this event?

**Edit**

I'm showing new fragments with this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(tag)
        .commit();
```

Should I change it somehow to make `onCreateView` get called? Since I'm adding new fragment B **on** existing fragment A (I can even click on a button which is in fragment A when B is on the screen), when I pop fragment B, nothing changes with fragment A's situation.

Answer (score 1):

Override this method in the Fragment and check the boolean value

```
   @Override
   public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        //Log.e("setUserVisibleHint", "isVisibleToUser " + isVisibleToUser);

   }
```

Put the code that you need to be executed whenever the fragment becomes visible/is hidden in this method, according to the isVisibleToUser boolean value

Comment: I tried this but this method never gets called. I checked couple of other topics, people say this method should be used to inform system, and not to listen changes.

Comment: I have used it successfully in my application, this was the only solution that worked. I had a viewpager with fragments being swiped left and right, and only this method detected whenever a fragment was actually on screen or not. I dont know what else to propose to you, as other solutions didnt work out for me

Comment: ViewPager might be calling this method automatically but since I don't use ViewPager in my app, probably I need something else. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @J.K. this method does not work unless fragment is used with ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try OnBackStackChangedListener this way?

```
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if(getFragmentManager()==null)
                    return;
                Fragment fr = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)//id of your container;

                if (fr instanceof BlankFragment2) {
                    //On resume code goes here
                }
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does what I want but the way doesn't feel correct. I will keep searching but still, thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will works.

1) Put/call **addOnBackStackChangedListener** on your **Activity**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(backStacklistener);
```

2) Define **backStacklistener** inside your Activity

```
FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener backStacklistener = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (manager != null) {
                Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
                if(fragment instanceof OutboxFragment) {
                    OutboxFragment currFrag = (OutboxFragment) fragment;
                    currFrag.onFragmentResume();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

3) Provide a method on your fragment that you want to be triggered. In this case I create method named **onFragmentResume()**

```
public void onFragmentResume() {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.showFab();
    // or do another thing here
}
```

Good luck!